# How to make the middle of 2 divs resizable to change sizing? (am using bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following layout:

I want to make it so that the user can put their cursor in the middle of content1 and content2 and be able to drag it left and right to resize it (making content1 bigger/content2 smaller. Is there a way to do this with my current code?
[image]

**CSS**

```
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .main-wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.header-wrapper{
  background-color: #009688;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-wrapper{
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.body-wrapper{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-1{
  background-color: #2DC050;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-2{
  background-color: #1FA325;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .content-1,
  .content-2{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="main-wrapper d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="header-wrapper fixed-top d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed header. I will be alwase visible on top. I'm fixed height.
  </div>
  <div class="body-wrapper d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-1 d-flex flex-column text-center">
        <h1>I'm content One. My position is left. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-2 d-flex flex-column">
        <h1>I'm content Two. My position is right. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper fixed-bottom d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed footer. I will be alwase visible on bottom. I'm fixed height.
  </div>
</div>
 Run code snippetExpand snippet
Header and Footer always fixed.
Content 1 and Content 2 will be scroll-able if browser min-width is 992px.
Entire page will be scroll-able if browser max-width is 991px.
Edit for Ronaldo comments. Answer is yes it's possible. Check the bottom snippet.

body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-wrapper{
  background-color: #009688;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-wrapper{
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.body-wrapper{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .body-wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.content-1{
  background-color: #2DC050;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-2{
  background-color: #1FA325;
  color: white;
  min-height: 700px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .content-1{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.content-2-1{
  background-color: #0D420F;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="main-wrapper d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="header-wrapper fixed-top d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed header. I will be alwase visible on top. I'm fixed height.
  </div>
  <div class="body-wrapper d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-1 d-flex flex-column text-center">
        <h1>I'm content One. My position is left. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-2 d-flex flex-column">
        <h1>I'm content Two. My position is right. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper fixed-bottom d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed footer. I will be alwase visible on bottom. I'm fixed height.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do this with only pure HTML and CSS properties.
Use the Jquery resizable() that allows you to resize divs by draggin.

```
<script>
   $( function() {
      $( "#divID" ).resizable();
   } );
</script>`
```

source: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/